# Онлайн-режим: нужен ли дефис?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

У меня появилась необходимость написать "онлайн()режим" - "Вопросы вы можете задать в онлайн()режиме". Я обычно пишу раздельно, но рука так и тянется поставить дефис.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужен он тут или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В РОС (2012) -- ***онлайн-режим***.

Так же и здесь: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EE%ED%EB%E0%E9%ED-%F0%E5%E6%E8%EC&all=x